# Energy conservation in the Sachs-Wolfe effect

Tags: energy, cosmology, gravity

When energetic photons climb out of a potential well (eg Sachs-Wolfe effect) they lose energy. According to conservation of energy, where does this energy go? Into the gravitational potential making it less steep or more shallow, or is it radiated away? Or do both effects occur?

Comment: Energy is not conserved in general relativity, and the Sachs-Wolfe effect is general relativistic in nature (the potentials appear initially as perturbations to the metric, and in certain gauges $\Phi$ corresponds to the usual Newtonian potential.

Comment: Let's forget about relativistic effects and stay with the Newtonian potential, eg the gravitational field of the Earth or the Sun. Can the question still be answered as the the energy differences involved are small?

Comment: Are you asking in terms of photons climbing out of a static potential?

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite right to say the light has "lost energy" climbing out of the gravity well.  It seems more accurate to say that observers at different places in the gravity well will measure the light with different energy, since energy (and frequency) are observer dependent quantities.

Comment: Another facet of observer dependence: a free falling observer who intercepts the light will not observe the redshift, i.e. will observe the spectral lines at their usual frequencies predicted by quantum mechanics

Answer (score -2):

It always amazes me that the frequency change is postulated during the movement of the photon in the gravitational gradient. Isn't the explanation that the frequency of the photon depends on the gravitational potential at the time of emission the simpler postulate?

Comment: No, because a different frequency is measured at different points.

Comment: @ProfRob You want to say that there are experiments where the receiver measures at different heights to the source? Interesting. Please a link.

Comment: Err, it's you who is suggesting new physics and needs to cite an experiment to show that General Relativity is incorrect.

Comment: However, your idea would suggest that astronauts on the ISS would measure GPS clock rates to be the same as those measured from the ground (after correcting for relative motion). If that were true, I think we would have heard by now ... In any case, I can't see how your hypothesis addresses the question.